# How to save value of textbox when clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a Window Form.  I have some textboxes appearing, what I need is to select two textboxes and save their values temporary, then press a button and compare them.

How does one do this is C# Visual Studio?

I can select the boxes but how do i save their value?

EDIT

i am able to click and two controls, like two textboxes and so on and highlight them.
 protected void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Rectangle selectionRectangle = this.ClientRectangle;

```
        var borderColor = Color.Tomatoe;
        var borderStyle = ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed;


        if (this.Selected == true)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(
                e.Graphics,
                borderStyle
            );
        }
    }


 void Rectangle_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Select();
        }

        public override void SetColor(System.Drawing.Color color)
        {
            this.textBox1.BackColor = color;
        }
```

Them i press a button to compare the selected controls, i need to create a method that gets the current control state and then compare the selected values that have this.Selected == true.

Comment: This is quite simple thing to do. What you have tried? Show some code here.

Comment: Sounds not a hard problem. Have you tried _anything_ to solve it?

Comment: Where do you want to save them?

Comment: save them where? `textbox1.Text` should suffice?

Comment: i am new to this, i was googling but don't know exactly how to look for it, so if possible please give me an idea

Comment: The idea is, i start the window form, in the interface i select two textboxes, i want to compare them, a window should popup with : they are the same or they are different

Comment: You don't need to google, you need to get a book for beginners and read it to understand basic things.

Comment: Mal, compare them how? In the same form? does this happen when you click on a button? during a method? does my previous comment apply?

Comment: @MAL. You could use `MessageBox` to show result. By pressing button, value in the Textboxes won't be lost. You could reterive values of Textboxes using `textBox1.Text` where `textBox1` is the name of your TextBox.

Comment: Sayse, yes, they are in the same form, and when i click the button the content of each textbox selected should be compared, i can select only two, and from there a new window with they are different or not should appear

Comment: Hassan, yes, but how do i retrieve the values os selected textboxes, what's the method name?

Comment: First tell what you exactly mean by `selected textboxes`? Is there any checkbox or what?

Comment: Since you are new to this: always read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and also read http://www.dotnetperls.com/windows - there are quite nice examples to a lot of things.

Comment: Hassan, no, there's no checkboxes, i just have a form and when i open a form, i select two textboxes and i need to compare their content, that's it

Comment: Btw you have more than 2 `textboxes` and you want to click on 2 of them and compare if they have same text inside? Think you need to add some `checkboxes` for that.. I think that if you included your actual code with your textboxes, it might help us to help you...

Comment: @MAL One simple does not select textboxes, you can have focus in ONE of them or you can "select"(get to them) in the code behind. But there's no such thing as clicking on 2 textboxes and selecting them as far as I know.

Comment: `i select two textboxes`... how you do that?

Comment: Yes, well, the textboxes are just normal, i mean i might have like 30 textboxes and i need to select each of them and compare

Comment: Ms.Nobody, yes, i can have focus on them, that's why i'm asking because i don't know how to proceed from here

Comment: Will be closed as unclear what you asking. Please add visualization of what you doing, show some code where you stuck. Now everyone have individual imagination of what you doing and trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with I'm going to assume you are able to create a button click event from there it should become straight forward.

```
private void buttonWithAGoodDescriptiveName_click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textboxWithDescriptiveName.Text == otherTbWithGoodName.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("woo it worked");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Doh!");
}
```

You don't need to save the values temporarily since you can directly access the contents of the textbox. You could create local variables in this method that would achieve the same thing but its pretty wasteful.

You can find out more information about some of the things used in this method using the MSDN documentation.

[TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can search for controls of a specifc color with the following

```
var controls = this.Controls
                   .OfType<TextBox>()
                   .Where(tb => tb.BackColor == Color.Red)
                   .ToList();

if(controls.Count > 1)
    if(controls.Skip(1).All(c => c.Text == controls.First().Text)
        MessageBox.Show("woo");
```

Assuming you have added the property selected to your own override of the textbox class you can change the controls variable to this.

```
var controls = this.Controls
                   .OfType<MyTextBox>()
                   .Where(tb => tb.Selected)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, so yes i know how to create a button, but i don't need to pre define the textboxes i'm comparing, i select them from the interface, i select them and i can see what i selected because i color them, and from there i compare, is this code still applicable for this?

Comment: @MAL - What do you mean you color them? you set their background colours?

Comment: yes, when selected, i color them so i know what i selected

Comment: Thanks for the update, so, when i open the form there's no coloring of course, just when i click the textboxes, so then it applies right?

Comment: @MAL - You stated that you already color them, if you don't then it sounds like you also want to apply a color using the TextBox.Click event

Comment: no, it's okay, i mean i just open the form, select the textboxes and they get colored, from there i can continue like this right?

Comment: @MAL - I think so, your question was how to compare two textboxes and display a message which I think this covers

Comment: Sayse, could you please check my edit?

Comment: @MAL - You don't override the paint event, you just use the click event (see the documentation link in my answer). If you are still struggling you may wish to do research and then if still struggling you should create a new answer that includes this research and attempt.

Comment: Well, this is a way to attempt to do it, and if you see the edited part again now in my question, what i need now is just a method that gets the current color, that i don't know how to do

Comment: Click on the textbox in designer, in the properties window, click on the lightning symbol, find the click event, click in the empty box and press enter.

Comment: Dear Sayse i'm not explaining myself, i know the color, because i set the highlight color, so if i select the textbox, since i added a property boolean selected, how can i compare the ones that selected == true?

Comment: added a final update.

Comment: Great thanks, just one thing, can you please edit it for all the control types, and create a method that returns the list i can use at the button click, i'm sorry, i know this is basic, but i have problems with the syntax, i can read the code but i'm not good with the rest

Comment: could you please edit that? i'm trying and i get errors..